# OpenCL Kernel: unsigned char -> signed char (aka cl_char)

Tags: objective-c, c, char, kernel, opencl

The following kernel accepts a `char*` array (*alphabet*):

```
  kernel void generate_cl(global char* alphabet,
                            global int* rand_buffer,
                            int len,
                            int max,
                            global bool *stop)
```

However, by compiling it becomes:

```
extern void (^generate_cl_kernel)(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_char* alphabet, cl_int* rand_buffer, cl_int len, cl_int max, bool* stop);
```

Obviously alphabet is now a cl_char (aka **signed** char).

My Problem: I need a **unsigned**/const char array. (see code below) 
My Question: How do I cast `unsigned char` to `signed char` (if possible)? Or is there any other approach?

```
const char* alphabet_ = ... //char array, received from [NSString UTF8String]
generate_cl_kernel(&range,alphabet,..); //throws semantic issue [!]
```

Comment: Why not just keep it as an unsigned char (e.g. declare as `uchar` inside kernel)?

Comment: hmm...now i'm getting "kernel generate_cl does not exist for device" (after removing bool parameter stop)

Comment: boolean types are not guaranteed to have same size on Host and Device sides, so you may have troubles in your case.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan This is why I removed it... I guess I have to use unsigned char instead...